# Why JAVA Library is not building in android aosp?

Tags: java, android, makefile, jar, android-source

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += \
    moniserv-flairclient \
    moniserv-gson

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(call all-java-files-under, src) \
    src/co/IMonitorService.aidl \
    src/co/IMonitorServiceCallback.aidl

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MonitorService
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS :=true

LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libandroid_main_jni_monitor
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES += \
    CmdWrapper

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

The above is actually present in MonitorService/ Android.mk file.

When I given mm, it throws an error that,

```
    MonitorService/Android.mk was modified, regenerating...
    ninja: error: 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/CmdWrapper_intermediates/classes-header.jar', needed by 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/MonitorService_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar', missing and no known rule to make it


even in android_build/
```

I given make framework and then executed `MonitorService` with mm
but still I get the same error.

Cmdwrapper is present in `MonitorService/userlibs/CmdWrapper.jar`

Answer (score 0):

You should prebuilt CmdWrapper. Here is an example: http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/apps/Dialer/Android.mk#418

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE := dialer-zxing-target
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../external/zxing/core/core.jar
LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: So instead of include $(BUILD_PACKAGE), I need to use BUILD_PREBUILD ?

Comment: No. Just use BUILD_PREBUILD to include the CmdWrapper. So you can use CmdWrapper in you app

Answer (score 0):

You should use "mma" command instead of "mm" command.

---

- mm: Builds all of the modules in the current directory, but not their dependencies.
- mma: Builds all of the modules in the current directory, and their dependencies.